# How to show solutions for quadratic formula

Tags: c#, math, quadratic, square-root

So I wrote a Quadratic formula program in C#, how do I take the quadratic formula program and modify it so that the program correctly displays the number of solutions.

if there are two solutions,

```
(x - x1)(x - x2) = 0
```

if there is only one solution,

```
(x - x0)^2 = 0
```

if there are no solutions,

No Solution.

This is the program, if someone could show the solution to this for me that would be wonderful, I'm really stuck on how to do it.

```
using System;

namespace quadraticequation
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number for a"); //ask the user for information
        double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Gets a from the user
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number for b"); //asks the user for information
        double b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Gets b from the user
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number for c"); //asks the user for information
        double c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Gets c from the user

        //double.Parse --> is used to convert a number or string to a double.
        //Console.ReadLine() --> is used to take the input from the user.

        //We call a function here
        Quadratic(a, b, c);

    }
    //We need to create a new function

    public static void Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) 
    {
        double deltaRoot = Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c); //Math.Sqrt takes the square root of the number


        if (deltaRoot >= 0)  // we use an if statement here to handle information
        {
            double x1 = (-b + deltaRoot) / 2 * a;  //We write the information for x1 here
            double x2 = (-b - deltaRoot) / 2 * a;  //We write the information for x2 here
            Console.WriteLine("x1 = " + x1 + " x2 = " + x2); //we use this to write the roots



        }
        else  // we use an else statement so that we dont return an error when there are no roots
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no roots");

        }



    }
}
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want only *Real* solutions, not Complex ones?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to review your *second degree formula solution*-skills. You write:

```
double deltaRoot = Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);
```

But the test is actually whether *b<sup>2</sup>-4×a×c* is larger than or equal to zero: indeed that is actually why we check it: because we cannot take the **square root of a negative number** (yeah there exist *complex* numbers that can take the square root of a negative number, but let's ignore that for now).

So the solution is to write it like:

```
public static void Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
    double delta = b*b-4*a*c; //only delta

    if (delta > 0) {
        double deltaRoot = Math.Sqrt(delta);
        double x1 = (-b + deltaRoot) / (2 * a);  //We write the information for x1 here
        double x2 = (-b - deltaRoot) / (2 * a);  //We write the information for x2 here
        Console.WriteLine("x1 = " + x1 + " x2 = " + x2); //we use this to write the roots
    } else if(delta == 0) {
        double x1 = -b/(2*a);
        Console.WriteLine("x1 = " + x1); //we use this to write the roots
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("There are no roots");
    }

}
```

You also have to write `(-b + deltaRoot) / (2*a)` (with `(2*a)`), otherwise you will *multiply* `(-b + deltaRoot) / 2` with `a` instead.

A final note is that equality comparisons with floating points is very tricky so `delta == 0` will often fail since the result can be something `1e-20`-ish, which is simply an error when performing floating point arithmetic. So it is perhaps better to use a small range of values.

This gives:

```
csharp> MainClass.Quadratic(1,1,1);
There are no roots
csharp> MainClass.Quadratic(1,1,0); 
x1 = 0 x2 = -1
csharp> MainClass.Quadratic(1,0,0); 
x1 = 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this.